# Xamarin Save SMS to Galaxy S5

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sms

```
    private void SaveToInbox(ShortMessages shortMessage)
    {
        var now = shortMessage.MessageDate.HasValue ? shortMessage.MessageDate.Value : DateTime.Now;
        var d = new Date((now.Year - 1900), now.Month - 1, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
        var context = Application.Context.ApplicationContext;
        var values = new ContentValues();
        values.Put("address", shortMessage.From);
        values.Put("body", shortMessage.Message);
        values.Put("read", false);
        values.Put("date", d.Time);
        context.ContentResolver.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
    }
```

The above code works fine on my Samsung Galaxy s3 mini however on my Samsung Galaxy s5 the message doesn't get saved into the phone sms inbox, can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know that on newer devices you have to set the Application as default sms manager in order to have the above code work